Expand a little complicated macro
The macro \usevar{} is defined in the below code and it can be expanded with \ExpandArgs{e} command. Is it hard to expand it with expandafter instead ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\def\csname var:#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\usevar#1{\csname var:#1\endcsname}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=22,cc=33,dd=44}

\usevar{aa}

\ExpandArgs{e}\ifstrequal{\usevar{aa}}{11}{True}{False} %output is True

\expandafter{\usevar{aa}}

\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\usevar{aa}}{11}{True}{False}
% output is False

\end{document}


You might be interested in How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?

You need one expansion to get \csname var:aa\endcsname one to get \var:aa then (only if you know the details of the implementation) one to get 11 so you need three expansion steps so seven \expandafter but there is no reason to ever do this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\def\csname var:#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\usevar#1{\csname var:#1\endcsname}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=22,cc=33,dd=44}

\usevar{aa}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\ifstrequal
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\usevar{aa}}{11}{True}{False}



\end{document}


So \usevar{} didn't store a value .

@xcn \usevar{}: The 1st expansion-step gets you \csname var:\endcsname. The 2nd expansion-step gets you the control-word-token \var:. As that is undefined, as a side-effecct of \csname that control-word-token is let equal to the primitive \relax only within the current and subordinate scopes (regardless \globaldefs' value). ...

@xcn ... (regardless \globaldefs' value). So within the current and subordinate scopes \var: is unexpandable, thus a 3rd expansion-step has no effect and in processing stages subsequent to expansion, e.g., typesetting boxes, the token \var: is \relax. Outside current and subordinate scopes \var: yields undefined-control-sequence-error.

@xcn You can test with \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\usevar{} versus \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\usevar{}.

@xcn "So \usevar{} didn't store a value" ?? as you can see from its definition \usevar isn't an assignment, it does not store anything. It just access a macro by name.

@DavidCarlisle Is it possible to get value directly by \usevar{} . I tried \edef\usevar#1{\csname var:#1\endcsname} . but it doesn't work.

@xcn I really can not guess what you are trying to do here, clearly you can not expand  \csname var:#1\endcsname at definition time, before the argument #1 is supplied, what would you want that to expand in to?

@UlrichDiez I think the OP was using \usevar{} as a generic reference not asking specifically about the empty argument and csname behaviour on undefined commands.

@xcn you have given no clue about your actual use case here but latex already has defined far more robust commands for accessing items from comma lists (the clist and seq modules) so almost certainly you should not be using etoolbox \ifstrequal  or any \expandafter here.

thank you @DavidCarlisle . I understand it now.

@xcn You can do \edef\macro{\usevar{aa}}. Then, before actually defining \macro, \usevar{aa} and everything coming from \usevar{aa} gets expanded in a "regurgitative process" until only unexpandable tokens and expandable tokens whose expansion was suppressed remain. Thus after doing  the above \edef-assignment, triggering one expansion step on the control word token \macro yields the unexpandable character tokens 11.

thanks @UlrichDiez . could you possibly explain why  \edef\macro#1{\usevar{#1}} \macro{cc} print nothing ?

@xcn what would you expect it to print? You are expanding \usevar before passing any argument, it is the same as your initial edef comment above

@xcn Unlike with \def, with \edef expansion is not suppressed when gathering the tokens forming the  of the . Therefore with \edef\macro#1{\usevar{#1}} the sequence \usevar{#1} and everything coming from \usevar{#1} is expanded in a "regurgitative process" at the time of defining \macro until only unexpandable tokens and expandable tokens whose expansion was suppressed (by \noexpand or \unexpanded or due to definition via \protected\def...)  remain before the assignment is done. ...

@xcn ... is done. In the course of expanding \usevar[#1} you get \csname var:#1\endcsname. In the course of this expansion # is an explicit character token of category 6(parameter) and 1 is an explicit character token of category 12(other). ...

@xcn ... of category 12(other). When in the course of this expansion expanding \csname, these character-tokens are just characters that form components of the name of the control-word-token to construct, thus at the time of defining \macro you get a control-word-token \var:#1 into the  of the definition where each character of the name of the control-word-token is just a character of that name, nothing special. ...

@xcn ... nothing special. Thus \macro is just a control-word-token defined to be a macro which at the time of being expanded causes TeX to grab tokens for an undelimited argument from  the token-stream, e.g., {cc},  and as replacement text to deliver a control word-token \var:#1 to the token-stream where the #1 of the name of that control-word-token has nothing to do with the argument #1 grabbed at the time of expanding \macro but is just two characters of the name of the control-word-token \var:#1 that came into being at the time of defining \macro. ...

@xcn ... of defining \macro. As at the time of defining \macro the control-word-token \var:#1 is undefined, as a side-effect of \csname TeX lets \var:#1 equal to the \relax-primitive within the current scope and subordinate scopes, thus \maco{cc} is replaced by a control-word-token whose name is \var:#1 (whereby # and 1 are just characters of the name) which in turn in the current scope and subordinate scopes is \relax. You can test with \show\macro and \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\usevar{#1}.

@xcn and now you see why it's a bad idea to ask further questions as comments on old answers, the site format really doesn't support it at all. It intentionally makes it hard to give long mult-line answers with code posted as comments

I see it. Thank you once again for everything you’ve done !
